# What does it mean if a Loki has no or some horns?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In the *Loki* show on Disney+, some Loki have horns.  Some don't.  More importantly, Sylvie starts the show with one horn, then goes down to zero.

I suspect there is a meaning behind having and not having horns, and in particular, does losing one or more horns tell us something about Sylvie's character?

Comment: It might be more accurate to say they wear horns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sophia Di Martino, the actress for Sylvie, has spoken in an interview about why Sylvie only has one horn at the start. It's because she's been on the run a long time doing a lot of fighting. It is also meant to represent her character at the point we meet her though, she's kind of broken and lost in the world and so is her crown.

> Sylvie's been on the run for a long time, she's been hiding out in apocalypses. She's been brawling a lot, she's been beating a lot of people up. I think the horn is probably broken somewhere along the line. It's also, I believe, inspired by the comics and the Lady Loki character. It says a lot about Sylvie - she's wearing a crown, but it's kinda broken.
>
> <sub>[ScreenRant, Sylvie's Broken Loki Crown Explained By Actor](https://screenrant.com/loki-sylvie-broken-crown-explained-sophia-di-martino/)</sub>

Sylvie eventually loses her crown on the train during the fight in episode 3. Again this is meant to help show the growth of her character. She doesn't need to hold onto the past anymore or hopes of ruling (we get more hints at this in episode 5) and she's growing as a person. We see her come more into her own and in a way move past the "Loki anger" and become Sylvie even more. She's also ready to leave the shadows behind and face the world.

> **What was it like opening up those fissures in the Loki pompousness and Loki attitude that you see in *The Avengers* in moments like the train scene?**
>
> The train scene I love because Loki doesn’t get many wins and it’s nice to see him having a nice sing-song. He’s just enjoying himself. Because I think that’s such a funny way, as well, to show the difference between him and Sylvie is that she’s on a mission. She’s like, “We’re going to get off this moon.” And when she’s offered a drink, she’s like, “No, thank you.” But Loki’s like, “Yeah, I’ll take the drink.” I remember I had this diagram with Christine from costume. People will see it as the show goes on, but across this episode in particular, Loki’s lost his Variant jacket. He doesn’t have that by the end, and it’s like, as a Loki, he’s transforming and in that sense, it’s almost like his outer appearance does as well, in the sense that his jacket’s gone, but also he gets more dirty. And Sylvie’s the same. She loses her horns on the train, and she loses that coat that we’ve seen her hiding under in the first two episodes.
>
> <sub>[thrillist, How 'Loki' Director Kate Herron Built Loki and Sylvie's Bond](https://www.thrillist.com.au/entertainment/nation/loki-kate-herron-interview/)</sub>

For a more general rule on this though, which you might want to apply to other Lokis and you might not, Hiddleston told Kate Herron, the director, the below.

> Herron was a big fan of the God of Mischief prior to signing on to direct the six-episode first season of "Loki," but she learned new things from Hiddleston.
>
> One of her major takeaways was Hiddleston's interpretation of Loki's signature gold horns.
>
> "He always felt that Loki wears the horns when he's feeling his most powerful or most in control, and I just thought that was really interesting," she said.
>
> <sub>[Insider, 'Loki' director Kate Herron says Tom Hiddleston's 'Loki lectures' on the Marvel character 'brought everyone together'](https://www.insider.com/loki-lectures-tom-hiddleston-kate-herron-interview-2021-6)</sub>

You can likely read into that regarding the other Lokis we see. Though it doesn't appear to be universally true when we consider that Boastful Loki never wears horns/a crown.

Comment: "six-episode _first_ season". Sounds like more seasons are projected. Good to know.

Comment: @FreeMan I do hope for more as I've enjoyed it but I wouldn't put too much faith in that line. It can still be the first and only season. Also that's written by the article writer and not a direct quote from Marvel. That being said there have been a few hints about a possible season 2, I guess we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: Episode 6, post-credits: "Loki will return in season 2"...

Comment: So, why does the main view point character of Loki have no horns.  Ever.  Is he fundamentally different from the others in some way other than being the main viewpoint?

Comment: @John Loki is broken at the start, he's just lost in New York and now his whole world has tipped upside down. As the series goes on he no longer wants to rule but has other motivations. In short anyway.

Comment: So, a Loki with horns wants to rule, and a Loki without does not?  During the first episode, my memory is that he's pretty clear he wants to rule.

Comment: @John Well it's not as black and white as that and sorry if I inferred as such. Look at the quotes in my answer as well and you'll probably be able to infer what I meant.